# Como pegar todas as keynames dentro do localStorage

Tags: javascript

Como pegar todas as **keyNames** *(não os valores)* dentro do localStorage e adicionar como `option` em um elemento `select`?

**Código em funcionamento [aqui](https://editor.sollic.com/)**

**Explicando o código:**

**1.** A função `salvar()` salva uma key com o nome determinado no `input`.
 **2.** A função `carregar()` pega a keyName determinada e envia como `option` para dentro do elemento `select`
 **3.** A função `limpar()` limpa o localStorage por completo

Porém o meu código apenas faz isso com uma key predeterminada, como faço para pegar todas as keyNames e coloca-las como `option`?

```js
var te = document.getElementById('te')
function salvar(){  
      localStorage.setItem(te.value, 'Qualquer coisa');
}
function carregar(){
      document.getElementById("op").innerHTML = "<option value='"+ localStorage.key(te.value) +"'>" +localStorage.key(te.value)+ "</option>";
}
function limpar(){
   if (confirm('Você tem certeza que deseja o localStorage?')) {
      localStorage.clear();
   } else {
    // Não faz nada!
   }
}
```

```html
<input id="te" placeholder="Digite um nome para a Key" />
<div class="salvar">
<button onclick="salvar()">Salvar</button>
<button onclick="carregar()">Carregar</button>
<button onclick="limpar()">Limpar</button>
</div>
<select id="op" name="lsKeys">
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) para isso. Ele retorna um `array` com todas as **chaves** do objeto.

Você pode usar algo assim:

```
const keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
console.log(keys);
```

Para criar os `<option>`s, você pode criar um laço `for`:

```js
// Mude o seletor abaixo conforme precisar:
const list = document.querySelector('ul');

const keys = Object.keys(localStorage);

for (const key of keys) {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.textContent = key;
  option.value = key;

  list.appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente com algumas alterações vlw ;)